# Error on Trying to Change Order End Date

Tags: error, order

I've built out a custom ordering application where some profiles can manipulate the order params - status, line items, end date etc.

The users are reporitng that they get an '`Entity locked down`' error when they try to change the order end date. We haven't changed anything in our app so has this setting changed somewhere in Salesforce?

Comment: Is there any approval process setup on the order object ?

Comment: Check triggers related to that object.

Comment: There are no approvals or triggers for it

Comment: @user5094  are you using `salesforce Locking Statements` any where(in trigger)? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With effect from Spring 14, there's a [limitation](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_sales_orders_limitations.htm) that users can't really change the order end date if there's an associated reduction order with it. You may want to check if that is the case with your order id.